# Delete remote registry keys via PS

Tags: powershell, registry

I am needing to use PowerShell to delete a registry entry from multiple computers. The only thing is that PowerShell scripts are not enabled on the remote computers. Is it possible to manipulate the registry of multiple computers from my computer? What command could I use?

Comment: There have been tons of questions and answers about [remote registry access via PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[powershell]+remote+registry). Please show some effort.

Answer (score 2):

There is a pre powershell registry tool called reg. It will perform registry operations on remote computers.

```
REG DELETE /?

REG DELETE \\Computer\HKLM\Software\MyCo /v MTU
  Deletes the registry value MTU under MyCo on Computer
```

If you have a list of computers in a list, then you can do something like this

```
$computers | ForEach-Object {
    REG DELETE "\\$_\HKLM\Software\MyCo" /v MTU
}
```

Comment: One thing i did forget to mention that i thought was unneeded since i asked for it in powershell... But i need it to loop through all user's sid's. So i need it to be able to handle foreach loops and arrays. So if there was some way i could grab all of the sid's remotely i could use reg for this.